# How to insert delimiters after each element?

Tags: jquery, append

I have, in a div, a few hyperlinks. The number of hyperlinks, however, varies. There's no saying what it will be. It can be One, Two, N. What IS known, is that there's always at least one hyperlink in the div.

I have, right now, the links in this format:

```
Link1 Link2 Link3
```

I want to convert it into:

```
Link1 | Link2 | Link3
```

I am facing two problems:

1. There is a pipe AFTER the last item - not good.
2. The Pipe, that gets inserted as hyperlink's text, and not between elements.

To overcome the first problem, I tried to insert pipe only if element is not the last one.
for the second problem, I have no idea what to do.. here's what I am doing so far:

http://jsfiddle.net/KL6Ua/

Also, I am not sure if there is a better way to solve the first problem. Advice please.

Thank you,.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like http://jsfiddle.net/k8Fzk/ ?

```
$("<span>|</span>").insertAfter($('#divLinks a:not(:last)'));
```

---

**Edit**, if you want to insert just a pipe character after each a element, you should use [after](http://api.jquery.com/after/) i.e. http://jsfiddle.net/W6RQH/:

```
$('#divLinks a:not(:last)').after('|');
```

Comment: Hello @stecb, great.. thanks, though, I don't quite get why delimiter has to be a span.. can you please explain? thanks

Comment: coz in that case, maybe setting `display:inline-block` to the span element, you can set a custom margin, color, etc :)

Comment: @stecb, so If I want, can I still put just a pipe character? tried that and it didn't want to work!

Comment: the pipe character is not a DOM node, therefore it will raise an expression error. In that case u should use after i.e. `$('#divLinks a:not(:last)').after('|');`

Comment: yes, @iamserious is correct, if i take out span, pipe is not working

Comment: oh i saw your reply a little late, thanks.. i think i understand now! need to go check the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

```
    if(index != 0)
        $(this).prepend(delimiter);
```

OK Updated..

```
<div id="divLinks">
    <span><a href="">One</a></span>
    <span><a href="">two</a></span>
    <span><a href="">three</a></span>
</div>



$(function() {

    var NumberOfLinks = $('#divLinks a').length;

    $('#divLinks a').each(function(index) {
        var delimiter = " | ";

        if(index != 0)
            $(this).parent().prepend(delimiter);
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi Steve, sorry, the pipe is still appearing inside the hyperlink and hence, it still is a link. not solving my second (and main) problem.

Comment: uh, sorry @steve, even without trying that code, I can say it's incorrect, as everytime pipe is appended to parent, all pipes are in one place and links in the other.. here's what your code is doing: http://jsfiddle.net/7s633/2/

Comment: If you look at your links, I had enclosed them in span elements which does make it work. Your jsfiddle is not what was suggested, but no problem.

Comment: Hi, aah yes I see, having a span works, but the whole reason I'm doing this in jquery is because I am not producing the page and i don't have control over it, i can only format after the page has been produced.. Thank you very much, too

Answer (score 1):

You have a **list** of links, so don't be afraid to use appropriate HTML tags for lists (*ul li*). Then, don't use Javascript for elements' decoration — CSS is a better tool.

http://jsfiddle.net/PcHSM/

Comment: Hi, that's quite a nice idea, but I do not have control over what goes into the page, I am to work on an already presented page with jquery to get things into place.. thanks.

Comment: Oh, ok. Anyway, you can use :before also for _a_ tags, _ul_ _li_ is just more semantic for creating lists.